Paracompactifying families of supports in Paracompacts spaces
A paracompacifying family of supports $\varphi$ on $X$ is a collection of closed subsets of $X$ s.t.

a closed subset of a member of $\varphi$ is in $\varphi$
$\varphi$ is closed under finite union
each element of $\varphi$ is paracompact
each element of $\varphi$ has a closed neighbourhood which is in $\varphi$

If $K\in \varphi$ and $Q\supset K$ is the closed neighbourhood that is given by 4, can we claim that $K$ is contained in the interior of $Q$?
Is this true under some assumptions on $X$ (e.g. paracompact) or is it in general false?
